# Select sum query

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I want to select on mysql database items with given quantity order by expiration date.
For example: SELECT 500 RM1181
output must be data with the ID 16 and 1. Because the priority is the item with the nearest expiration date. which is itemID 16 expires first but its only 100 so i need the next item which is itemID 1

below code is what I currently have.

```
SELECT
O.ID,
O.itemcode,
O.qty,
O.expdate
(SELECT
 sum(qty) FROM put_in
 WHERE itemcode = 'RM1181') 'RunningTotal'
 FROM put_in O WHERE itemcode = 'RM1181'
 HAVING RunningTotal >= 500 ORDER by expdate
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us 1) sample data for the `put_in` table, and b) your expected output.

Comment: I don't understand the running total.  How are you computing this?

Comment: The running total is supposed to be the needed qty.

Comment: 100 + 600 > 500 ... I don't follow your math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.ID, t.itemcode, t.qty, t.expdate, t.total
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.ID,
           t1.itemcode,
           t1.qty,
           t1.expdate,
           (SELECT SUM(t2.qty) FROM put_in t2
            WHERE t2.expdate <= t1.expdate AND t2.itemcode = 'RM1181') AS total
    FROM put_in t1
    WHERE t1.itemcode = 'RM1181'
) t
WHERE t.total - t.qty < 500 AND
      t.itemcode = 'RM1181'
ORDER BY t.expdate;
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I had a typo in there, sorry.  The subquery should be labelled `t2`, not `t1`.

Comment: The output is item with qty 600 and 1800. it should be 100 and 600 based on the expdate sir.

Comment: For next time, please include sample data and expected output.  The better the question, the faster you get help.

Comment: Hi sir, is it possible to output 400 on the total column of the second row instead of 700? so that the sum of the total column will be the qty needed which is 500 in the given example.

Comment: @RecaPot Try [this demo](http://rextester.com/RVYYT44305).  I won't update my answer, because you've substantially changed your question.

Comment: got it. thank you for your help sir! :) very much appreciated.